# Flutter App do not showing open option after being installed from Play Store

Tags: android, flutter

I have successfully deployed my app to the play store. It’s working fine when testing with a real device.

But when I download it from the play store, there is no `open` button , and I can’t find the app in my app drawer or anywhere else.

It is quite strange and I hope someone who also encountered this issue can advise me on this.

Thanks you

Comment: try to update your app to android 12 and update your `intent` according to document

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi BIS Tech,thank you. But I’m using a device with android 10 to download from play store. Does it impact android 10 as well?